# invalid syntax errror in elif loop using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

```
try:

    if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
        ref_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename + '_ref', LNG)
        if not os.path.exists(ref_filename):
            with open(ref_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                f_pcm.write(payload)

        cur_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename, LNG)
        with open(cur_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
            f_pcm.write(payload)
    else:
        print "[ERROR] No Resposne From the Server"
        sys.exit(Error_Status)
    compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename)
    elif content_type == "application/json":
        with open(get_filename('json', output_filename, LNG), 'w') asf_json:
            f_json.write(payload)
except:
    print "\n[ERROR] Can't Create Reference PCM or Response JSON files!"
    Error_Status = 1
```

I am trying to print Error message if the IF loop in my above code does not execute. so I am using if loop then later else loop to print the error message. later I am comparing the files. then I am doing elif statement. I am doing all those things within try and except block. But I am getting the error as

```
elif content_type == "application/json":
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: pls put elif before else and also check the indentation.

Comment: Check your indentation. If `compare_files` should be inside the `else`, give it 4 extra spaces. If `compare_files` should be outside of the `if-elif-else`, put it 3 lines down.

Comment: I want to compare the files then elif statement. what shall i do for that ?

Comment: I want to print error message after the if loop. but how to modify my code to do like that ?

Comment: By reading/watching tutorials on conditionals.

Comment: First result returned from googling 'python if tutorial' explains this quite sufficiently.

Comment: Nobody has said it yet loud enough: `if` **is not** a "loop". I don't know if you have a problem with the "loop" concept or the `if` structure or both. Look at some basic tutorials ([like the official one](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html)) and you will surely understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because an `elif` clause must occur *before* the `else` clause. Here is an outline of the correct way to do it:

```
if condition_1:
    print('condition_1')
elif condition_2:
    print('condition_2')
...
elif condition_n:
    print('condition_n')
else:
    print('no condition satisfied')
```

Correcting your code involves moving the `elif` clause and its body to before the `else` clause:

```
try:
    if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
        ref_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename + '_ref', LNG)
        if not os.path.exists(ref_filename):
            with open(ref_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                f_pcm.write(payload)

        cur_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename, LNG)
        with open(cur_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
            f_pcm.write(payload)
    elif content_type == "application/json":
        with open(get_filename('json', output_filename, LNG), 'w') as f_json:
            f_json.write(payload)
    else:
        print "[ERROR] No Resposne From the Server"
        sys.exit(Error_Status)

    compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename)
except:
    print "\n[ERROR] Can't Create Reference PCM or Response JSON files!"
    Error_Status = 1
```

A couple of things:

- Shouldn't `len(payload)` also be checked when the content type is
  JSON?
- You shouldn't use a bare `except`, you should explicitly define the
  exceptions that should be caught.
- In the `else` clause the error message says that there was no
  response from the server, however, there may well have been a
  response it's just that it has an unhandled content type.